# ActiveStorage Image import from Remote URL via activerecord-import gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, activerecord-import

I am trying to import list of products via CSV, there is an image column with remote url. I am using activerecord import gem, when I use the setup below I don't get any errors or logs but images are not being created.

```
    require 'open-uri'
    file = open(row['image'])

    product = Product.new(
        name: row['name'],
        sku: row['sku'],
        brand_id: row['brand']
    )
    product.image.attach(io: file, filename: row['sku']+ '.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg')
    products << product
end

importing = Product.import products, recursive: true
```

am I missing something? Or is there a better way to handle this.

I was able to import image with regular csv parse. Still not sure, why activerecord import didn't work. I think I will ask this in the gem's github.

```
csv_text = resp.body
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'utf-8')
csv.each do |row|
    file = open(row['image'])
    t = Product.new
    t.name = row['name']
    t.image.attach(io: file, filename: row['name']+ '.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg')
    t.save
    puts "#{t.name} saved"
end
```

Comment: seems like the code you shared is not complete?

Comment: Hey draganstankovic, i only put the relevant part of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Giving these prompts as an answer then:

The part of the code you shared (assuming other parts behave as expected) seems ok and like it is doing what it should but since your images are not created ... 
(removed guesses part)

**Edit**: after your update revealing some context, my guess is that the first version (with `ActiveRecord` import) didn't work as the import gem doesn't invoke callbacks and/or probably skips something that is required for `ActiveStorage` to trigger the upload of the file attachment.

Comment: thanks for your input @draganstankovic, I was able to import when I am not using activerecord import gem. Updated the issue with working version.